# Access denied when downloading file from Sharepoint CSOM

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I am trying to download a file from a client Sharepoint site. I am using sharepoint CSOM.

My code is as follows:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

var username = "username";
var password = "pass";

var url = "https://myclient.sharepoint.com/";
var fileurl = "https://myclient.sharepoint.com/teams/folder1/folder%20x/somefile.docx";
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(url))
{    
    SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
    context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, passWord);

    Uri filename = new Uri(fileurl);
    string server = filename.AbsoluteUri.Replace(filename.AbsolutePath, "");
    string serverrelative = filename.AbsolutePath;

    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(serverrelative);
    context.Load(file);
    ClientResult<Stream> streamResult = file.OpenBinaryStream();
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    var file2 = streamResult.Value;
}
```

The problem is that I get access denied, yet when I log in with the same credentials, I can download the file successfully.

- Is there a separate permission in Sharepoint for downloading file from API instead of UI?
- Could the space in the folder name be the problem?

**UPDATE**

Verified this does not have anything to do with spaces in folder or filename.

Answer (score 0):

In case if SharePoint site uses [multiple authentication providers using a set of Windows credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh124553(v%3Doffice.14)) (also relevant for SharePoint Online), the additional header must be included in a request: `X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED` with a value of `f`

For [`ClientContext` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcontext.aspx) the header could be included like this:

```
ctx.ExecutingWebRequest += (sender, e) =>
{
    e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Headers["X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED"] = "f";
};
```

Example

```
var file = ctx.Web.GetFileByUrl(fileAbsUrl);
ctx.Load(file);
var streamResult = file.OpenBinaryStream();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();


//save into file
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(@"C:\path\filename.docx"))
{
   streamResult.Value.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
   streamResult.Value.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

> Note: instead of converting to relative url, [`GetFileByUrl`
>   method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getfilebyurl.aspx) is used which accepts *absolute* url

Comment: Im having a hard time finding this GetFileByUrl method. I see it on MS Docs, but every sharepoint client nuget package I try to download is missing it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I was not connecting to the right url (**new ClientContext(url)**)

I was connecting to: https://myclient.sharepoint.com/

I should have been connecting to: https://myclient.sharepoint.com/teams/folder1/